# SMTP: Change from:address field?

Tags: email, smtp

Is it feasible to have an SMTP server change the FROM address of an email, concealing the master account?

POBox informed me that it was possible with their service, thing on "how you establish your email customer".

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use an email forward or mailing list attribute of your smtp server if you have that. If you Google best smtp server, that server really has the attribute of mailing listing and you could set up a mailing list with just one individual in it so when you send an email to that listing, it's going to be forwarded to that person and "From:" e-mail address is going to be changed to the From: e-mail address of the list owner.

Comment: Actually, the SMTP server has much more control than that, and could change every aspect, even deciding whether to send the email or not, add/remove attachments, update/edit content, add / remove recipients etc. Of course, such a server doesn't do well in business ( :) ) , but it is possible to do pretty much anything.